# @Assert\NotBlank validation not working in embedded form in symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony4

I have a form called **BlockType** which has an embedded form called **BlockHeroStaticImageType**. The field called '**title**' of the embedded form **BlockHeroStaticImageType** contains validation annotation `@Assert\NotBlank()` as shown below (see  **BlockHeroStaticImage Entity** below).
When I leave the **title** as empty in the form and try to save the form, the form validation is not triggered. The validation should fail, but it is not the case. I checked `$form->isValid()` in the controller and it is returning true despite the title being emtpy. What am I missing here? Please help.

***BlockType Form***

```
class BlockType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('content', TextareaType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'ckeditor',
                    'data-field' => 'content'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('blockHeroStaticImages', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => BlockHeroStaticImageType::class,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
                'label' => 'Hero Static Image',
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'help' => '<a data-collection="add" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="#">Add Hero Static Image</a>',
                'help_html' => true,
                'attr' => [
                    'data-field' => 'blockHeroStaticImages'
                ]
            ]);

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Block::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

***Block Entity***

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\BlockRepository")
 */
class Block
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $content;

   /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Block\BlockHeroStaticImage", mappedBy="block", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
    */
    private $blockHeroStaticImages;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->blockHeroStaticImages = new ArrayCollection();

    }

    ...


    /**
     * @return Collection|BlockHeroStaticImage[]
     */
    public function getBlockHeroStaticImages(): Collection
    {
        return $this->blockHeroStaticImages;
    }

    public function addBlockHeroStaticImage(BlockHeroStaticImage $blockHeroStaticImage): self
    {
        if (!$this->blockHeroStaticImages->contains($blockHeroStaticImage)) {
            $this->blockHeroStaticImages[] = $blockHeroStaticImage;
            $blockHeroStaticImage->setBlock($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeBlockHeroStaticImage(BlockHeroStaticImage $blockHeroStaticImage): self
    {
        if ($this->blockHeroStaticImages->contains($blockHeroStaticImage)) {
            $this->blockHeroStaticImages->removeElement($blockHeroStaticImage);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($blockHeroStaticImage->getBlock() === $this) {
                $blockHeroStaticImage->setBlock(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

***BlockHeroStaticImageType Form***

```
class BlockHeroStaticImageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class, [
                'required' => false
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => BlockHeroStaticImage::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

***BlockHeroStaticImage Entity***

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Block\BlockHeroStaticImageRepository")
 */
class BlockHeroStaticImage
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $title;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Block", inversedBy="blockHeroStaticImages")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $block;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking in [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html) you are supposed to call `$validator->validate($object)` before sending form.

Also, not sure if it works now but syntax provided in documentation for adding NotBlank constraint is `@Assert\NotBlank`, without brackets.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried both, still not working.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with `by_reference` property and how it maps to functions, but can you maybe change name of your add and remove functions to addBlockHeroStaticImages and removeBlockHeroStaticImages, with an 's' in the end? Because this is the name of a property you're adding.

Comment: Those are auto generated functions when I setup the OnetoMany relation. Those are not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue in Symfony 6. Fixed by adding `#[Assert\Valid]` to the `OneToMany` property in the parent/owner's entity.

This constraint is documented here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html

> This constraint is used to enable validation on objects that are embedded as properties on an object being validated. This allows you to validate an object and all sub-objects associated with it.

In OP's case, and using annotations as well, the fix would be:

```
/**
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Block\BlockHeroStaticImage", mappedBy="block", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
  * @Assert\Valid()
  */
private $blockHeroStaticImages;
```